# Cannot obtain metadata from WCF service hosted on local machine's IIS

Tags: web-services, iis, metadata, config

I have a WCF web service hosted on my local machine's IIS, but when I try to use svcutil to get the metadata I get the following:

```
Attempting to download metadata from 'http://mycomputer.mydomain:port#/R
eportsService/n_datafactory.svc?wsdl' using WS-Metadata Exchange or DISCO.
Microsoft (R) Service Model Metadata Tool
[Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Communication Foundation, Version 3.0.4506.2152]
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from http://mycomputer.mydomain:port#/ReportsService/n_datafactory.svc?wsdl

If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have acce
ss, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified addr
ess.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentat
ion at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.


WS-Metadata Exchange Error
    URI: http://mycomputer.mydomain:port#/ReportsService/n_datafactory.svc?wsdl

Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
'http://mycomputer.mydomain:port#/ReportsService/n_datafactory.svc?wsdl'.

There was no endpoint listening at http://mycomputer.mydomain:port#/
ReportsService/n_datafactory.svc?wsdl that could accept the message. This is oft
en caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present
, for more details.

The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.


HTTP GET Error
URI: http://mycomputer.mydomain:port#/ReportsService/n_datafactory.svc?wsdl

There was an error downloading 'http://mycomputer.mydomain:port#/ReportsService/n_datafactory.svc?wsdl'.

The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request.

If you would like more help, type "svcutil /?"
```

My config file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WideTransferBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="WebServSpace.n_datafactory" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceNameBehavior">
    <endpoint bindingConfiguration="WideTransferBinding" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WebServSpace.n_datafactory" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<!--For debugging purposes set the includeExceptionDetailInFaults attribute to true-->
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceNameBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you browse to the URL do you see the test page? If you browse to the wsdl do you see it?

Comment: Yes and yes, and they both display the correct information